# Groovy 4 fails to recognize static interface method

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

Starting with Groovy 4.x, one cannot call interface static methods.

For example, with Groovy 4.0.16:

```
groovy:000> Random.getDefault().nextInt(10)
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: static java.util.Random.getDefault() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

And the same code with Groovy 3.0.9

```
groovy:000> Random.getDefault().nextInt(10)
===> 5
```

Both examples are run on Java 17, where the `getDefault()` method is part of the JDK, see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGenerator.html#getDefault()

I found this bug report https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8693 but it looks like it has been fixed in Groovy 4 which is really ironic considering the above example.

What am I missing? How can this be fixed?

Comment: one obvious workaround is to do `new Random().nextInt(10)` - this do work

Comment: This is a static method inside the parent interface, and not a default interface method (so I think the subject is missleading). It also works, when called on the parent `java.util.random.RandomGenerator.getDefault()` (4.0.16, JVM: 21.0.1) - something's off with the inheritance?

Comment: Good point. Updated the title and the text to reflect it is a static method.

Comment: I previously raised an issue about this, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-10764 but apparently it's working as expected

Comment: That is sad. Groovy always was a 'drop-in' replacement for Java - that is, one could have taken a piece of java code and pasted it in a groovy file, and it should have worked. I guess that is no more.

Comment: This seems to be related as well: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-10590